# Cruising at the speed of sound

Tags: commercial-aviation, aircraft-physics

Is it possible or feasible for an aircraft to continuously cruise at the speed of sound? Is the drag at this point higher or lower than in the high Mach 0.98 or Mach 1-1.2 region?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the following plot (from [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/91807)), the F16 has a drag coefficient which doubles at transonic speeds but then remains basically constant past Mach 1.

[image: F-16 drag coefficient from Ray Whitford's Fundamentals of Fighter Design lecture]

So an F16 could definitely do it. And for a more modern aircraft, the rise in drag would even be more contained.

Comment: I'd like to see that plot for an F-22 or other fighter that can cruise supersonically without reheat for comparison.  Not sure if the F22 needs reheat to get there, then can cruise at military power, or if it can go moderately supersonic with military power alone.

Comment: @JohnK: I'd also like to see that... and obviously the one of the Concorde  For a supercruiser (like the Concorde) I'd expect only a peak in the drag coefficient at transonic speeds. Afterwards the coefficient should be just a bit higher than at subsonic speed.

Comment: @JohnK the Super Tomcat would also have been able to supercruise.